# jQuery 1.7.2 not working in IE8. Works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

**SOLUTION 8/9/2012 9:54 EDT**
Embarrassing as it is, we were able to track down the issue to the browser settings.  Active scripts were disabled.  Thanks to everyone who posted.  I appreciate your time & effort.  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I recently started on a new MVC3 application and we are using jQuery 1.7.2.  Currently our code works in Chrome, Firefox and IE7 & 9.  Unfortunately it is not working in IE8. It doesn't matter what jQuery function (mouseover, mouseout, hover, click, etc.) we are trying to use.

So far I have tried the following without any luck.

- using absolute path reference to jQuery and js files
- move js code directly onto _Layout.cshtml
- verify type="text/javascript"
- reduce code to just Alert("any text"); and verify in an alternate browser
- add background-color
- remove reference to "Menu.js" to test if the very simple code in Shared.js works

I am trying to get the .hover action to work on the _ActionItems partial view.  The jQuery for this is in Menu.js.  I figured if I can get that to work, the rest will probably have a similar solution that I can figure out.

If there is anything else you need to see, just let me know.  Thanks in advance for the help.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@using eRecruitBoard.ExtensionMethods
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Shared.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Menu.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="aboveHeader">
                <div class="aboveHeaderLeft">@Html.Partial("_ERBLogo")</div>

                <div class="aboveHeaderRight">
                    <div class="ERBESBButtons">@Html.Partial("_ERBESBButtons")</div>
                    <div class="welcome">@Html.Partial("_Welcome")</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="headerBar">
                <div class="headerActions">@Html.Partial("_ActionItems")</div>
                <div class="headerMenu">@Html.Action("Menu", "Menu")</div>
                <div class="headerTitle">@Html.Action("HeaderTitle","Segment")</div>
            </div>
        <div class="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div class="Push"></div>
  </div>  
    <div class="footerWrapper">
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footerLeft"></div>
            <div class="footerRight"></div>
            <div class="footerRightContent">@Html.ActionLink("Privacy Policy", "PrivacyPolicy", "Home")</div>
            <div class="footerLeftContent">&copy; Copyright 2012 - All Rights Reserved</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**_ActionItems.cshtml**

```
@if (eRecruitBoard.WebLibrary.CommonFunctions.IsAuthenticated)
{
@Html.ImageActionLink("../../Images/Header/FavoriteIcon.png", "FavoritesIcon", "Add", "Favorites", null, null, new { @class = "over", title="Add to favorites", style="border:0;" })<text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
<img src="../../Images/Header/CalendarIcon.png" title="Schedule this report" alt="CalendarIcon" class="over"/><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
<img src="../../Images/Header/EmailIcon.png" title="Email this report" alt="EmailIcon" class="over"/><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
<img src="../../Images/Header/PrintIcon.png" title="Print" alt="PrintIcon" class="over"/>
}
else
{ 
}
```

**Shared.js**

```
// Hover image
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("img.over").each(function () {
            var t = $(this);
            var src1 = t.attr("src"); // initial src
            var newSrc = src1.substring(0, src1.lastIndexOf(".")); // let's get file name without extension
            t.hover(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", newSrc + "Over." + /[^.]+$/.exec(src1)); //last part is for extension   
            }, function () {
                $(this).attr("src", newSrc + "." + /[^.]+$/.exec(src1)); //removing 'Over' from the name
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE** - I removed the menu.js code so I could add the browser source.  I am focusing on the Shared.js code for now as it's much simple and causes no action even when Menu.js is totally removed.

**Sample of browser source** - Mind you this is one of the test I was running where I moved the jQuery directly onto the page and I added the alert.  Regardless, this doesn't work as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>eRecruitBoard</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
// Hover image
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
$("#container").hover('',function(){ 
alert("Out"); 
});
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("img.over").each(function () {
            var t = $(this);
            var src1 = t.attr("src"); // initial src
            var newSrc = src1.substring(0, src1.lastIndexOf(".")); // let's get file name without extension
            t.hover(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", newSrc + "Over." + /[^.]+$/.exec(src1)); //last part is for extension   
            }, function () {
                $(this).attr("src", newSrc + "." + /[^.]+$/.exec(src1)); //removing 'Over' from the name
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="aboveHeader">
                <div class="aboveHeaderLeft"><a href="/"><img alt="eRecruitBoard" src="../../Images/eRecruitBoardLogo.png" style="border:0;" /></a></div>

                <div class="aboveHeaderRight">
                    <div class="ERBESBButtons"><img src="../../Images/Header/ERBOn.png" alt="eRecruitBoard On"/><img src="../../Images/Header/ESBOff.png" alt="eScoreBoard Off"/>
</div>
                    <div class="welcome">Welcome Firstname Lastname&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="/Admin/MyTeam">Admin</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="/Home/Logout">Logout</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="headerBar">
                <div class="headerActions"><a href="/Favorites/Add"><img alt="FavoritesIcon" class="over" src="../../Images/Header/FavoriteIcon.png" style="border:0;" title="Add to favorites" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="../../Images/Header/CalendarIcon.png" title="Schedule this report" alt="CalendarIcon" class="over"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="../../Images/Header/EmailIcon.png" title="Email this report" alt="EmailIcon" class="over"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img id="container" src="../../Images/Header/PrintIcon.png" title="Print" alt="PrintIcon" class="over"/>
</div>
                <div class="headerMenu"><img src="../../Images/Header/MenuIcon.png" id="MenuIcon" title="Click to open the menu" alt="MenuIcon" class="over"/>
<table class="menuTable" id="menuTableId"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr class="scrollUpArrow">
<th>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr class="scrollDownArrow">
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>

 <tbody id="contents" class="tablebody" style="overflow:hidden">
    <tr class="trmenuClass" id=favoritestrId>
    <td class="cellBackground">
    <div class="minusSign" id=favoritesMinusSignId>  
    <div class=favIcon id=divFavoritesid>
    <div class="cellName">

    Favorites
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="favtrClass" id="submenufavouritestrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idFavorites">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    1st name
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="favtrClass" id="submenufavouritestrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idFavorites">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    2nd name
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="favtrClass" id="submenufavouritestrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idFavorites">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    3rd name
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trmenuClass" id=dashboardtrId>
    <td class="cellBackground">
    <div class="minusSign" id=dashboardMinusSignId>  
    <div class=dashboardIcon id=divDashBoardid>
    <div class="cellName">

    Dashboard
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dashboardtrClass" id="submenudashboardtrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idDashboard">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Dashboard Item 1
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dashboardtrClass" id="submenudashboardtrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idDashboard">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Dashboard Item 2
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dashboardtrClass" id="submenudashboardtrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idDashboard">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Dashboard Item 3
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trmenuClass" id=connecttrId>
    <td class="cellBackground">
    <div class="minusSign" id=connectMinusSignId>  
    <div class=connectIcon id=divConnectid>
    <div class="cellName">

    Connect
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="connecttrClass" id="submenuconnecttrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idConnect">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Joe Smith
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="connecttrClass" id="submenuconnecttrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idConnect">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Erin Jones
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="connecttrClass" id="submenuconnecttrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idConnect">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Owen Alexander
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trmenuClass" id=hiretrId>
    <td class="cellBackground">
    <div class="minusSign" id=hireMinusSignId>  
    <div class=hireIcon id=divHireid>
    <div class="cellName">

    Hire
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hiretrClass" id="submenuhiretrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idHire" >
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Clair Brown
    </div>  
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trmenuClass" id=retaintrId>
    <td class="cellBackground">
    <div class="minusSign" id=retainMinusSignId>  
    <div class=retainIcon id=divRetainid>
    <div class="cellName">

    Retain
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="retaintrClass" id="submenuretaintrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idRetain">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    some good employee name
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trmenuClass" id=activityreportstrId>
    <td class="cellBackground">
    <div class="minusSign" id=activityreportsMinusSignId>  
    <div class=activityIcon id=divActivityReportsid>
    <div class="cellName">

    Activity Reports
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 1
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 2
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 3
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 4
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 5
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 6
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 7
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 8
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 9
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 10
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 11
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activityreportstrClass" id="submenuactivityreportstrId">
    <td class="subMenuCell" id="idActivityReports">
    <div class="subMenuCellName">
    Activity report 12
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>


</table>
</div>
                <div class="headerTitle"><img src="../../Images/Header/TitleArrow.png" alt="Arrow" style="vertical-align:top;"/>
<ul class="segmentControl">
</ul>
</div>
            </div>



        <div class="content">

<h2>Homepage</h2> - <a href="/Dashboard/All">Link to Dashboard/All</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Push"></div>
  </div>  

    <div class="footerWrapper">
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footerLeft"></div>
            <div class="footerRight"></div>
            <div class="footerRightContent"><a href="/Home/PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a></div>
            <div class="footerLeftContent">&copy; Copyright 2012 - All Rights Reserved</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem at all?

Comment: Oh, and I have also tried using older versions of jQuery (eg, 1.5.1)

Comment: That's painful. Help us by giving us what is the problem. Debug it ...

Comment: What errors are you getting in the Developer Tools for IE? Also, can you post what the browser is seeing, rather than the server-side code that generates it?

Comment: Are you actually testing with IE8, or something like IETester? I've had trouble with those tools in the past.

Comment: @Sam - Besides narrowing it down to jQuery in IE8, I have not been able to narrow it down anymore:(  Basically in IE8, it acts as though the jQuery doesn't exist.  No error message.  Nothing.

Comment: @TimS Is the site online? Are we able to take a look?

Comment: @Sam it is not online at the moment but I may be able to get the ports open to share with your guys this afternoon.

Comment: Please, reproduce the problem with a shorter code.

Comment: @Cavyn VonDeylen - I am using an actual IE8 browser on our server. 8.0.6001.19222 to be exact.

Comment: -1 for code dump and lack of research effort.

Comment: @Saint Gerbil , seriously?  I listed six different attempts that I researched and posted in my second paragraph.  Did you read this paragraph?

Comment: @TimS. Browser issues occur once the code has gotten to the browser, so the server-side code is only relevant if it's causing malformed HTML. However, without **seeing** what's being generated, there's no way to know if that's the case. If you're short on characters, replace the server-side code with the generated HTML, and cut it back to the important parts (specifically the `<script>` tags, but may as well include the entire `<head>` tag).

Comment: @Anthony Grist Thanks.  I removed menu.js code and added the browser source for the last test I was running. JS code is directly on the html page removing any file reference.  All removed all references to menu.js to just focus no a very small test with .hover.

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassing as it is, we were able to track down the issue to the browser settings. Active scripts were disabled.

Tools > Internet Options > Security> Click Custom Level button > Scroll down to Scripting > Active Scripting

Thanks to everyone who posted. I appreciate your time & effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(function () {
    $("#container").hover('',function(){ 
        alert("Out"); 
    });
    $("img.over").each(function () {
        var t = $(this),
            src1 = t.attr("src"),
            newSrc = src1.substring(0, src1.lastIndexOf("."));
        t.hover(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", newSrc + "Over." + /[^.]+$/.exec(src1));
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", newSrc + "." + /[^.]+$/.exec(src1));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note here is you are doing document.ready twice in these lines

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () { // this line does the same as $(document).ready(function () {
```